# Why are public procedures in peripheral files prefixed with MX_***?

Tags: coding-style, stm32, hal

public names of procedures that CUBE generates have a prefix MX_***.

For example can.h:

```
/* USER CODE END Private defines */

void MX_CAN_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN Prototypes */
```

What does `MX` mean? I mean, how does `MX` stand for.

P.S. I know that from a functional point of view, it doesn't matter what the procedure is called.
This is a codestyle question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that these functions don't have any parameters, still they magically configure the relevant modules. This is because they are not pre-defined library functions; instead their definitions are auto-generated by the STM32CubeMX during project generation, specifically for your project and configuration.

For comparison, the pre-defined library functions start with `HAL_` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

`MX` is just used as this is code generated by [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html). It avoids naming conflicts in C/C++. MX doesn't have any special meaning besides being part of the CubeMX name.